# Drupal 8 Custom Composite Masked Input

Tags: webforms

Are masked inputs supported in custom composites?

I've tried the following and it doesn't break but it also doesn't mask.

```
$elements['job_details']['job_phone'] = [
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#input_mask' => '(999) 999-9999',
  '#title' => t('Company Phone Number')
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get simple form elements to include webform element enhancements you have to 'initialize' the composite's sub-elements using `\Drupal\webform\Element\WebformCompositeBase::initializeCompositeElements`

Comment: Composite elements currently don't initialize nested sub-elements within containers like fieldsets.
see https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2946226

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else came here (like me) looking for a way to add an input mask to a custom composite created through the [Webform Composite Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_composite) UI, you just need to add a custom property to your (sub)element:

```
input_mask: '''alias'': ''currency'''
```